# Vertically aligning text on a uikit overlay

Tags: html, uikit

i have the following code that is a image with a clickable overlay. When hovering over it displays the text Full Name. The problem i'm having is that it displays the name at the top of the overlay and not in the middle.

I can't see where my code is wrong?

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-3">
    <a class="uk-thumbnail uk-overlay-toggle" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal-ps'}" >
        <div class="uk-overlay">
            <img width="180" height="120" src="images/_sml.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="uk-overlay-area">
                <div class="uk-overlay-area-content"><b>Full Name</b></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="uk-display-block uk-text-center uk-margin-remove">
        <div id="modal-ps" class="uk-modal">
            <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
                <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close uk-close-alt"></a>
                <img width="540" height="360" src="images/lrg.jpg" alt="">
                <h3>Full Name</h3>
                <p>CEO</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, as you can see the "full name" div is centered on the overlay

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.24.0/css/uikit.min.css" />
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-3">
    <a class="uk-thumbnail uk-overlay-toggle">
        <div class="uk-overlay">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/180x120">
            <div class="uk-overlay-area">
                <div class="uk-overlay-area-content"><b>Full Name</b></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.24.0/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
```